# How to call `super` in a block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have a block of code. It was:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def configuration_with_cache
    Rails.cache.fetch("user_#{id}_configuration") do
      configuration_without_cache
    end
  end
  alias_method_chain :configuration, :cache
end
```

I want to remove the notorious `alias_method_chain`, so I decided to refactor it. Here is my version:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def configuration
    Rails.cache.fetch("#{id}_agency_configuration") do
      super
    end
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work. <del>The super enters a new scope. How can I make it work?</del> I got `TypeError: can't cast Class`, and I misunderstood it.

Comment: FYI, English an sentence ends with a period, not a comma.

Comment: If you are using a specific library or framework, mention that (if there is a tag, then tagging is enough).,

Comment: @sawa Thanks for your advice and sorry for my bad english :D

Comment: is it a module or class?

Comment: @Ilya Yes, it's a class that extends ActiveRecord::Base.

Comment: How about just replacing `alias_method_chain` with two `alias_method` calls?

Comment: Add `user_self=self` below `def configuration`, and then in the block call `super` by `user_self.super`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So we are going to bring `alias_method_chain` back? Is there a better way to make it work? I think it's the last option if there's no other ways, thanks.

Comment: @HFX: why do you think `alias_method_chain` (or what it does) is bad?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev alias_method_chain was good at removing duplicated aliases, but it also came
with a few problems of its own. For a start, alias_method_chain is just an encapsulation
of an Around Alias (134), and Around Aliases have the subtle problems
that you might remember from The Thor Example, on page 133. To make things
worse, alias_method_chain turned out to be too clever for its own good: with all
the method renaming and shuffling that was going on in Rails, it could become
hard to track which version of a method you were actually calling.
 (refer: Metaprogramming Ruby)

Comment: @HFX: ah yes, great book.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To start off, calling `super` in blocks **does** behave the way you want. Must be your console is in a corrupted state (or something).

```
class User
  def professional?
    Rails.cache.fetch("user_professional")  do
      puts 'running super'
      super
    end
  end
end
User.new.professional?
# >> running super
# => false
User.new.professional?
# => false
```

Next, this looks like something [`Module#prepend` was made to help with](http://gshutler.com/2013/04/ruby-2-module-prepend/).

```
module Cacher
  def with_rails_cache(method)
    mod = Module.new do
      define_method method do
        cache_key = "my_cache_for_#{method}"
        Rails.cache.fetch(cache_key) do
          puts "filling the cache"
          super()
        end
      end
    end
    prepend mod
  end
end

class User
  extend Cacher

  with_rails_cache :professional?
end
User.new.professional?
# >> filling the cache
# => false
User.new.professional?
# => false
```

Answer (score -1):

you can user Super in block.

please see this, any issues let me know.

Calling it as just 'super' will pass the block.
super(*args, &block)' will as well.

Comment: I don't follow you. I think maybe you misunderstood what the problem is. What I want is calling `super` in the block and pass the block to another method, and keeping the `super` in the scope that creates the block. That is, the `super` should be the super of `User#configuration`, instead of the super of the method that calls the block(`Rails.cache.fetch` here).

Comment: @HFX: interesting, this doesn't reproduce in my experiments.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You are right. In fact I got `TypeError: can't cast Class
`, and I misunderstood it.